# Same column name, different metadata for different content types?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, metadata

I am trying to set up two content types for two different products:

- `Product A` content type.
- `Product B` content type.

Within each of these I want to build a same column called `Customer`. 
However in each of these content types I need the metadata to be different. For example within `Product A` content type, I want to link `Customer` column with `Product A` metadata, such as AFF, CHH, DGG, however within `Product B` content type, I want to link `Customer` column with another `Product B` metadata, such as app, lee, baa.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can have the same display name but not the same internal name (obviously). 
So when creating the column for each content type name it (prodACustomer) and choose the proper data type and save it (this will create an internal name), then you can edit the column and rename it to Customer (the internal name won't change) and you do the same for the second column on the other content type. (Name it prodBCustomer) and then save and rename it to Customer and you should be ok

Comment: but  when I choose view style to display these two columns in document library, should I choose one Customer column or two Customer columns? Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand your questions correctly, you need to have a view for each content type, so you have to select the correct column (Customer) in the corresponding view